# How do cookies work on Mac?

Tags: macos, cookies, safari

On Mac the cookies are shared between all applications, I understand that.
So if I delete cookies in my app, it will delete them in Safari, and say I delete all the google.com apps, I will find when I open Safari that I am logged out in Safari as well as the app.

However, after having deleted the cookies, I log in to Google from my app, when I open Safari I will still be logged out and have to log in there as well. So it seems cookie creation is not synchronised between apps?

But, after having deleted all the cookies again, if I log back into Google from Safari, when I open my app I will be logged in there as well, so the creation of cookies have been synced across.

Secondly if I use `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, to delete cookies (from within my app) the app must then be restarted before it takes effect?

What are the rules and details of how the shared cookie storage works on a Mac?

Comment: "shared between all applications" = applications using the system-provided WebKit. Certainly not between Firefox and Safari. And probably not with Chrome either.

Comment: Well deleting cookies in an app certainly deletes them in safari, and the app can access cookies created by safari. I know it is only webkit, safari uses webkit (admittedly probably a less restricted version than apps can use). So I know firefox and chrome(which uses webkit but it's own version) won't be affected.

Comment: FWIW, it does not have to be that way, take a look at Fluid for example, which (only in the paid version) offers "Apps with Separate Cookie Storage". http://fluidapp.com/. So I guess there is an API to manage your own cookie jar, but it takes extra effort.

Comment: @Jonathan. , I am looking to delete cookies of WKWebview in my mac app. I have tried with NSHTTPCookieStorage and also with FileManager, but i am not able to delete. It's not working for me. Please suggest is there any other way to delete cookies in OS X app.